# How to update multiple Mongo documents manually in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise

I have a collection of `users` in MongoDB. I need to generate a token for each user and save it to the database:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
db.users.find({}).exec(function(users){
    users.forEach(function(user){
       user.token = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
       user.save();
    });
});
```

I'm always confused about async methods and just can't understand how they work... So this code doesn't work beacuse it exists before the `save()` calls finish. How would you make it work? How would you wait for all the `save()`˙calls and print `Done!` to console?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose `find` function returns a promise, you can use it to create chain. `Promise.all` produces promises (or a mix of promises and values), iterate over all the values and return a promise that is fulfilled when all the items in the array are fulfilled.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

db.users
    .find({})
    .then(users => {
      var ops = users.map(user => {
       user.token = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
       return user.save();
      });
      return Promise.all(ops);
    })
    .then(() => console.log('done'))
    .catch(err => console.log('error' + err));
});
```

Comment: What does "=>" mean ? I'll try your solution soon.

Comment: `=>` means [ES6 arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). If you use node.js version< 4, use usual `functions` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works flawlessly.